# Является ли хорошей практикой создание тысяч потоков java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Если высоконагруженная программа будет создавать 10000-100000 java threads эти потоки будут максимально равномерно использоваться всеми ядрами процессора, или это плохая практика?

Comment: Тут получится наоборот. Если программа создаст 100000 потоков, то она автоматически станет высоконагруженной, так как процессор только и будет заниматься переключением между потоками.

Comment: Если коротко, то да, операционная система будет пытаться равномерно распределить работу потоков (с учетом приоритетов), чем она и занимается с процессами.

Comment: Плохой практикой является  то, чтобы программировать бездумно, чего бы это ни касалось, потоков, памяти и прочих ресурсов